# Question about arranging $6$ identical balls into $3$ identical boxes

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

The problem description is as follows:

> $6$ Identical balls are randomly placed in $3$ identical boxes. What is the probability that each box will have $2$ balls?

My attempt:

The total number of arrangments is $3^6$. The arrangement $(2,2,2)$ is one such arrangement. Therefore the probability is $\frac{1}{3^6}$. However, this is incorrect. Thus, I have 3 questions

1. What is wrong with my solution?
2. Please provide a detailed solution explaining all the small details.
3. Is there a standard method to solve such questions? I find them confusing especially because there are so many different ways questions can be asked(like distinct balls in distinct boxes or identical balls in distinct boxes etc.)If not, how do I think about and approach such questions to prevent errors in the future?(i make lots of silly errors in probability and PnC questions)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: +1 for 5Xum, he perfectly explains the fundamentals. The standard method is to think, not to learn automatic methods and 'pick' one magic formula from a catalog. Another rule in such exercices is to always consider that balls are distinguishibles (it is my opinion, other people may think differently). And to be totally conscious that you have to adapt the process if balls are considered as not distinguishibles. Balls are distinguishibles, there is $3^6$ arrangments, how many of them match with the constraint  "2 in any box" ?

Comment: I think the distinct arrangements are: (0,0,6), (0,1,5), (0,2,4), (0,3,3), (1,1,4), (1,2,3), (2,2,2). there are $7$ of them, not $3^6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when you are using Combinatorics to attack a probability problem, and you want to express the answer as $\displaystyle ~\frac{N\text{(umerator)}}{D\text{(enominator)}},~$ you have a decision to make.

Should you consider the balls as distinguishable or not.  Since this is a probability problem, rather than only a problem in enumeration, you are permitted  to go either way.

That is, as long as you are consistent between computing $~N~$ and $~D,~$ you can consider the balls to be distinguishable or not.

It is irrelevant that you are given that the balls are indistinguishable, because being able to distinguish the balls does not affect the probability of achieving a 2-2-2 distribution.

With this problem, it will be more convenient, when computing both the numerator and denominator, to assume that the balls are distinguishable.

---

For the denominator, the assumption that the balls are distinguishable leads to the very convenient computation of

$$D = 3^6,$$

as indicated in the answer of 5xum.

---

As for computing the numerator, there are $~\binom{6}{2}~$ ways of deciding which two balls will go into bin-1.  Then, for each such selection of two balls into bin-1, there will be $~4~$ balls remaining, and $~\binom{4}{2}~$ ways of deciding which two of the $~4~$ remaining balls go into bin-2.

So, the probability is

$$\frac{N}{D} = \frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}}{3^6}. \tag1 $$

---

**Addendum**
The approach taken in (1) above may be **sanity-checked**, by using a similar method to compute all possible distributions, and verifying that the sum of these enumerations is $~3^6 = 729.~$

To expedite this, note that

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = [1+1]^n = 2^n.$$

Then, the number of balls that go into bin-1, will be some element $~r \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}.$

Assume that $~r~$ balls go into bin-1.

Then, the number of balls that go into bin-2 will be some element $~s \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,6-r\}.$

So, the number of distributions associated with placing $~r~$ balls into bin-1 will be

$$\binom{6}{r} \times \left[ ~\sum_{s=0}^{6-r} \binom{6-r}{s} ~\right]$$

$$= \binom{6}{r} \times 2^{6-r}.$$

So, the sanity checking occurs by verifying that

$$\sum_{r=0}^6 \left[ ~\binom{6}{r}2^{6-r} ~\right] = 729. \tag2 $$

Note that the sanity checking verification of (2) above may (instead) be done *analytically* by consideration of the binomial expansion of

$$(2 + 1)^6 = \sum_{r=0}^6 \left[ ~\binom{6}{r}2^{6-r} ~\right].$$

Comment: (+1), good answer. I realised that counting combinations of what we want and then dividing by total number of combinations doesn't work because the probability of each combination happening is different to the probability of other combinations occurring. So permutations is easiest anyway, because the probability of each permutation happening is the same. This is because the probability that the number $6$ falls into a box (which is is $1/3$) is not affected (i.e. independent) by what box the number $3$ falls into, etc. So the probability of each permutation occurring is $1/3^6.$

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for the great answer. I really liked your approach of assuming that the balls are distinct to solve the problem. Are there any other such techniques that can be used to make solving such combinatorics and probability questions easier? Could you expand on some, possibly in chat?

Comment: @Boson Yes there are, but it is not practical to attempt to discuss them at MathSE, even in a chat.  Further, I actually am generally ignorant of Probability/Combinatorics Theory, so I am the wrong person to ask anyway.  My suggestion is that you listen to your subconscious, which I would speculate, is telling you to find the right Probability book for you, open it to page 1, attacking, and then rinsing and repeating with the right book on Combinatorics.

Answer (score 2):

> What is wrong with my solution?

The total number of arrangements is $3^6$ only if you are able to distinguish between the balls.

For example, you can only count to $3^6$ if the following two arrangements are considered *different* arrangements:

- Box 1: balls $1,2,3$, Box 2: balls $4,5$, Box 3: ball $6$.
- Box 1: balls $1,3,5$, Box 2: balls $2, 4$, Box 3: ball $6$.

However, in this kind of counting, there is more than one good arrangement, i.e. you cannot just say that (2,2,2) is the only good arrangement.

> Please provide a detailed solution explaining all the small details.

It will be much more useful to you if you find the correct solution yourself, now that you know what went wrong in your first attempt. The only three ways to get better at this are practice, practice, and practice.

> Is there a standard method to solve such questions?

Not really, except for the three sure-fire methods mentioned above.